# how to print a binary tree diagram?

Tags: java, formatting, binary-tree

How can i print a binary tree in java so that the output is like:

```
        cat
        /\
     cat1 cat2
```

the values can be more than one character.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the dot program from [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for this.  There is an easy [online demo](http://ashitani.jp/gv/) of it.  This way you don't have to worry about spacing or font widths.

Answer (score 3):

```
    cat
    /\
 cat1 cat2
```

A binary tree consists of

- a root node
- a left subtree
- a right subtree

To print such a tree, we want to print the left and right subtrees one besides the other (with at least one space), and then print the root node over it, centered over the middle of both subtrees, and connected with ASCII lines. For this to work, we need to know how wide both subtrees are.

Use these ideas and recursion to create your tree-drawing.

---

Here is a method specification which may be useful:

```
/**
 * creates an ASCII-drawing of a binary tree.
 * @param node the root node of the tree in question
 * @return a String[] of the individual lines of the drawing.
 *    The first line contains the representation of the root node,
 *    the last line only leaf nodes, interim lines may contain
 *    line drawing characters or interior nodes.
 * 
 *    All the contained strings have the same length (are padded
 *    with spaces, where necessary).
 */
String[] drawTree(Node node) {
   ...
}
```

To output the tree, you then only have to do this:

```
for(String line : drawTree(root)) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

So, how could we implement our `drawTree` method?

- What would it do for leaf nodes (i.e. nodes without children)?
- If we have a non-leaf node, how can we combine the results of two such calls (for the left and right subtree), i.e. two String arrays as specified, to another string array as said? (First have a look at the simple case where both arrays have same length, i.e. the trees have same depth.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete, runnable Demo, which is a rush translation from Scala code, so it isn't idiomatic Java.

There are two implementations, one which takes a Tree and produces a JTree from it, another one which uses drawString and fits the Tree to the JFrame size.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*; 
import javax.swing.JTree;

/**
    (c) GPLv3 2010-09-24
*/
class MNode {

    MNode l; // left
    MNode r; // right
    int t;   // value

    public MNode (int t, MNode l, MNode r) {
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void add (MNode mn) { 
        if (l == null && t > mn.t) 
            l = mn;
        else if (t > mn.t) 
            l.add (mn);
        else if (r == null) 
            r = mn;
        else    r.add (mn);     
    }
}

abstract class NodePrinter {

    abstract void nodeprint (MNode root);
    int max (int a, int b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
    int depth (MNode n) 
    {
        if (n.l == null && n.r == null) return 1;
        if (n.l == null) return 1 + depth (n.r);
        if (n.r == null) return 1 + depth (n.l);
        return 1 + max (depth (n.l), depth (n.r));
    }
}

class SwingPrinter extends NodePrinter {

    void nodeprint (MNode root) {   
        JFrame jf = new JFrame ("Mein Freund, der Baum, ist tot");
        jf.setSize (380, 380);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        JTree jt = new JTree (translate2SwingTree (root));
        jf.add (jt);
        openSubnodes (0, jt);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation (WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
        jf.setVisible (true);
    }

    /**
        Open current branch.
        We need TreePath AND row.
        Open the MNode, iterierate with the row one step, and check there, 
        whether the Branch is a part of the new branch. 
        @param row the row of the starting MNode. 
    */
    void openSubnodes (int row, JTree jt) {
        TreePath tp = jt.getPathForRow (row);
        jt.expandRow (row);
        if (tp.isDescendant (jt.getPathForRow (row + 1)))
            openSubnodes (row + 1, jt);
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode translate2SwingTree (MNode ast) 
    {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode dmtn = new DefaultMutableTreeNode ("" + ast.t);
        if (ast.l != null) 
            dmtn.add (translate2SwingTree (ast.l));
        if (ast.r != null) 
            dmtn.add (translate2SwingTree (ast.r));
        return dmtn;
    }   
}

class TreeCanvas extends JPanel {

    private MNode root;
    private NodePrinter np;

    public TreeCanvas (MNode root, NodePrinter np) {
        this.root = root;
        this.np = np;
        d = np.depth (root);
        rows = (2 * d); // - 1
        cols = 2 << d;
    }

    private int d;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;

    // @override 
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        Dimension dim = getSize ();
        int xf = dim.width / cols;
        int yf = dim.height / rows;
        int fontsize = (xf + yf) / 2;
        g.setFont (g.getFont().deriveFont (fontsize* 1.5f));
        xyPrint (root, dim.width/2, dim.width/2, 1, xf, yf, g);
    }

    /**
        ___50 60 70__________________
      10    |     x0    x0-x1:  (50,30) - (60, 10)  
      20    |    /  \   x0-x2:  (60,10) - (70, 30)
      30    |  x1    x2
    */
    void xyPrint (MNode n, int x, int dx, int y, int xf, int yf, Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setStroke (new BasicStroke (3.0f));

        g.drawString ("" + n.t, x - xf, (y+1) * yf);
        g.setColor (Color.BLACK);
        if (n.l != null) {
            g.drawLine (x - (dx/2) + xf, (y+2) * yf, x, (y+1) * yf); // line:Up
            xyPrint (n.l, x - dx/2, dx/2, y + 2, xf, yf, g);
        }
        if (n.r != null) {
            g.drawLine (x + xf, (y+1) * yf, x + (dx/2), (y+2) * yf); // line down
            xyPrint (n.r, x + dx/2, dx/2, y + 2, xf, yf, g);
        }
    }
}

class ColorSwingPrinter extends NodePrinter {

    void nodeprint (MNode root) {   
        JFrame jf = new JFrame ("Rootnode");
        jf.setSize (650, 520);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        jf.add (new TreeCanvas (root, this));
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation (WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible (true);
    }
}

class RootNode extends MNode {

    public RootNode (String s) 
    {
        super (Integer.parseInt ("" + s.charAt (0)), null, null);
        for (String elem: s.substring (2).split (" "))
        {
            int i = Integer.parseInt (elem);
            MNode mn = new MNode (i, null, null);
            super.add (mn);
        }
    }   
}

public class NodePrinterTest {

    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        String param = "6 7 4 3 8 2 9 5";
        /*              6
                     4      7
                3       5       8
            2                       9
        */              
        RootNode root = new RootNode (param);
        ColorSwingPrinter printer = new ColorSwingPrinter ();
        printer.nodeprint (root);
        SwingPrinter printer2 = new SwingPrinter ();
        printer2.nodeprint (root);
    }   
}
```

Printing your Tree needs of course some adaption, since your Nodes will probably not have public attributes l, r and t, but you should be able to translate them to left () or setLeft ()/getLeft () and so on.

I don't remember where ColorSwingPrinter got it's name from - it should be named ResizingCanvasPrinter or something like that. I'm sorry.

Here is a screenshot of both implementations:
[image]

Centering longer texts like cat, cat1, cat2 will need adjustment. By now, the first character is placed at the center of the descendants